# Unclickable region on VSCode UI when installed on Chromebook / ChromeOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, window-manager, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have installed VSCode on my Lenovo Yoga Chromebook and I am unable to use the mouse in the bottom right corner of the UI. The problem has persisted through restarts, toggling the Terminal window, switching to 2 column layout, and a VSCode upgrade. To clarify:

- I can move the cursor within the problem area with the arrow keys fine, and select text as normal.
- The problem spans different VSCode UI elements - text editor, terminal and notifications (i.e. I cannot dismiss plugin notifications, or enter the terminal via that part of the UI)
- The problem area does not coincide with the ChromeOS control panel.
- The problem does not occur in Chrome, or other programs on the Chromebook.

I installed **VSCode** via the **.deb** in the Linux terminal. The version info is below:

- Version: 1.43.2
- Commit: 0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50
- Date: 2020-03-24T07:52:11.516Z
- Electron: 7.1.11
- Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
- Node.js: 12.8.1
- V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
- OS: Linux x64 4.19.87-07826-g55ab70aff690

I have attached a screenshot showing what happens when I drag diagonally up from the bottom right corner of a file of `.` characters, to illustrate.

[image: Screenshot]

**Does anyone know how I might solve or debug this?** We have a fair few of these Yoga chromebooks for our devs, and nobody else has reported this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this problem was related to the way the VSCode window was being launched by Chrome. I was able to work around this by using [Sommelier](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Sommelier-(A-more-native-alternative-to-xiwi)) to launch the app under Unity, and tweak the scaling / DPI to get a native resolution.

The solution was therefore to change `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=sommelier -X --scale=1.0 --dpi=160 /usr/share/code/code "--unity-launch %F"
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/com.visualstudio.code.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=sommelier -X --scale=1.0 --dpi=160 /usr/share/code/code "--new-window %F"
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/com.visualstudio.code.png
```

Note the `Exec=...` lines, with `--unity-launch`, and `--scale... --dpi...`
You may need to install Sommelier first. I didn't, but my device is managed.

Comment: Worth noting that there was an extra layer of complexity for my setup, as I was using an external monitor in portrait mode. This cause the 'dead area' problem to occur again (I had unplugged it to debug the problem). I have since switched to landscape mode on the external monitor, and the sommelier / unity window is working normally again. It's probably worth checking any external monitor setup if you encounter this problem.